# I want viewport to fill screen, and canvas to strech to fit that

Tags: html, cordova, canvas, viewport

I am developing a Hybrid app using cordova.

I want the canvas to fill the viewport along with all that is drawn on it.

The app is for iOS, and I have configured the config.xml file: `name="EnableViewportScale" value="true"` I think the problem is in the HTML file. What do you guys think?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
            <title>
            </title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <canvas id="a" width="310" height="490" >
                Your browser does not support HTML5...
            </canvas>
            <div></div>
            <!--script src="cordova.js"></script-->
            <script src="fastclick.js"></script>
            <script src="sourceCode.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```